# How to get full url address in phantomjs with python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, web-crawler

I am not getting full URL if I use phantomjs. It retrieves only this part

```
www.xyz.in/Magic-Bucket-Microfiber-Spinning-Rotating/dp/B00IWAWKK8
```

But the actual URL is as below

```
www.xyz.in/Magic-Bucket-Microfiber-Spinning-Rotating/dp/B00IWAWKK8/ref=sr_1_1?m=abc&s=a-b&qid=122222
```

So, How do I retrieve full URL including parameters?

Comment: how about other browsers like chrome and firefox?

Comment: It is showing full url in other browser. But i wanted to use only phantomjs so can you help me with this - @TarunLalwani

Comment: try this `print(driver.execute_script("return document.location.href;"))`. See if that helps?

Comment: It didn't work because i am scrapping all urls in a page but your code displays current page url

Comment: Can you get `page_source` and see if the correct urls are there in page?

Comment: yes the urls are mention above

Comment: Post the code you have used

Comment: tree.xpath(xpath_hash["ProductLink"])[0]

Comment: How does that tell me anything? Post your sample script, how you find element and then what you execute to get the href attribute?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(@id,"result")][1‌​]/div/div[4]/div[1]/‌​a/@href')

Comment: How come you are passing `@href` into the xpath. For selenium you are supposed to just go to the node in xpath and not use attributes

Comment: By using @href we can get the url address for that anchor tag.